# Spring automatically uses fastTime instead of Date?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot test in which I perform get request for a resource and I am checking then the returned JSON, however when dates are being returned I have the fastTime instead of the actual Date object and I cannot find the reason behind this?

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes= SpringApplication.class)

public class CarResourceIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void should_return_aggregates_with_child_portfolios() throws Exception {

        String returnedJSON = mockMvc.perform(get("/resource/car/EA/b?p=1000235"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();

    Car[] car = GsonTestUtil.getGson().fromJson(returnedJSON, Car[].class);

  }
}
```

Should I  configure something additional in order for the Date to be taken?
When I debbug the code I see that the date is in the correct format which is date, but when returned from the mockMvc.perform(...) I get the fastTime and I have an exception that the date cannot be parsed because it is fastTime